# Import .csv AzureADUser script only returns 100 entries

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I have exported a list of 270 user accounts from O365, all my shared mailboxes, what I want to do is pull the department field of each of those accounts.
But the output from cmdlet Get-Mailbox which I used to get my sharedlist.csv doesn't include the department information.

I know AzureADUser does, so, I am trying to loop through the sharedlist.csv and pull the displayname, UPN, and Department for each addresses listed in the sharedlist.csv

What I'm trying to figure out is how to have Get-AzureADUser pull only the information on the users I have listed in my CSV file.
Here is the command that I have so far:

Import-Csv 'C:\PowerShell Scripts\sharedlist.csv' | ForEach {Get-AzureADUser -All $True | Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department}

This is obviously not working for what I'm trying to do. It outputs in the format I want and shows the data, but it is pulling every Azure Ad User and then looping over and over. If someone can point me to the proper syntax needed to get this job done I'd appreciate it.

TIA

Comment: that does not look like a CSV file - there is no header line. since you didn't use the `-Header` parameter, that means the 1st line will be the header ... and i rather doubt that will match any of the property names that `Get-AzureADUser` is expecting. ///// so, what is in the Import BEFORE you send it to the pipeline?

Comment: UserPrincipalName
A.Y@domain.com
a.p@domain.com
A.S@domain.com
a.d@domain.com
a.b@domain.com
a.j@domain.com

Comment: Hi Lee, I don't know how to paste a bit of the CSV while maintaining anonymity. Please just assume that it is a CSV with 270 rows of email addresses in a single column. The problem is I am trying to import a list of 270 users and extract the Displayname, UPN, and Department from AzureAD

Comment: At no point do you refer to the piped in email addresss (`$_/$PSItem`), so what do you expect?

Comment: I should have explained, I'm a total n00b to scripting in Powershell, is there an example you can provide of how I could rewrite this simple script to get the results I need?

Comment: I've added the header UserPrincipalName to my CSV row and then tried a single line that looks like this:
Import-Csv 'C:\PowerShell Scripts\sharedlist.csv' | ForEach-Object $_.UserPrincipalName {get-azureaduser -all $true | Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department}
But that's returning all users and it loops.

Comment: @CudaPrime - you can add the CSV data to your original post. if you can't figure out the formatting, someone will fix that. [*grin*]

Comment: @CudaPrime - since you did not call `Get-AzureADUser` with a parameter, it is likely defaulting to either `-ObjectId` or `-SearchString`. that may be the reason you are getting unexpected results ... matches that you didn't anticipate. ///// there is an `-All` parameter that may be needed to get more than the 100 records you are getting back.

Comment: Thanks Lee, What I'm trying to figure out is how to have Get-AzureADUser pull only the information on the users I have listed in my CSV file. I would have thought the ForEach command after importing the CSV was what I needed to do, but that's obviously not how this works. :(

Comment: Just have a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0). In Example 2: Get a user by ID, you can see the cmdlet can have a `-ObjectId` parameter that accepts a UserPrincipalName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lee_Daily already explained in his comment, you are using the `Get-AzureADUser` cmdlet without any parameter, so it returns info about any user, not only the ones you have defined in the CSV file.

If your file (I peeked in the original question) looks like this:

```
"UserPrincipalName"
"user1@domain.com"
"user2@domain.com"
"user270@domain.com"
```

Then this should work for you:

```
$data = Import-Csv 'C:\PowerShell Scripts\sharedlist.csv'
$data | ForEach-Object {
    Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.UserPrincipalName  | Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you! That got it!